# Magento2, print page is obscure with login fields but only in chrome?

Tags: magento2

I notice something very strange. When I try to print any page on my magento2 website using chrome it is obscure with a login field, however this is not true for firefox? Is there a way I can prevent this? I think it some kind of strange css z-index issue but I don't know where to begin looking for the issue.

[image]

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm

Comment: You can use CSS to hide it by @Media Print Read more here